# How to apply Material Design Facebook button in android

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk

I'm using `compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.7.0'`
and:

```
<com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
      android:id="@+id/tutorial_button_login"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
      android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
      android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
      />
```

But the button looks so ugly: [image: Example]

Is there any way to make it look materialized or more cooler?

Comment: You can create your own image drawable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up setting paddings.

```
<com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
      android:id="@+id/tutorial_button_login"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
      android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
      android:paddingBottom="16dp"
      android:paddingTop="16dp"
      android:paddingRight="16dp"
      android:paddingLeft="16dp"
      android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical"
      />
```

Answer (score 7):

I tried to mimic the **Material raised button** described in  [Google's Material Design specifications](https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/buttons.html#buttons-flat-raised-buttons), this is what I could do :
[image: Facebook login button that looks like Material raised button]

To cover **pre-lollipop** versions, I used the properties of the **CardView** support library :

```
 compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.0'
```

I put the **LoginButton** inside the **CardView** :

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="6dp"
    card_view:cardBackgroundColor="#ffd9d9d9"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="6dp">

    <com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton xmlns:fb="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/login_button"
        android:layout_width="190dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
        android:paddingBottom="12dp"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingRight="16dp"
        android:paddingTop="12dp"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        fb:com_facebook_login_text="log in with facebook"
        fb:com_facebook_logout_text="log out from facebook" />

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

To remove the little **f** icon from the original login button, I added this to the java **LoginButton** instannce :

```
mButtonLogin.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null, null, null, null);
```

Comment: I prefer to use the default one, no code to maintain.

Comment: ok :) the flat button (using only paddings as you did) also makes it look good and clean.